# Why am I getting parameter value as null?

Tags: java, liferay

I hooked login.jsp and wrote following code in it:-

```
    <script>

    function a(){
    var otp=document.getElementById("otpText").value;
    document.location.href="?otp="+otp;
    <% System.out.println(request.getParameter("otp")); %>    //printing null
    return false;
    }

    </script>

    <form name="otp" method="post" action="" >
    Enter otp:
    <input type="text" name="otpText" id="otpText"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="return a()"/>
    </form>
```

I typed some value inside otpText and that value is displayed in the url when I submitted the form. But when I am printing that value as in above code,it is printing null. I need that value as I want to store the same into session.Please help, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You print out the Parameter bevor the request is sent!!! request.getParameter() works after the request is sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your code to

```
var otp=document.getElementById("otpText").value;
console.log (otp);  // or alert (otp);
document.location.href="?otp="+otp;
```

you will see the value.

Comment: then how can I store it into session??

Comment: session is control by the server side.  If you are actually calling a servlet, then you will be able to add it.